# updating variable from within update panel

Tags: c#, ajax, updatepanel

im trying to update a variable from within an update panel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var v = 1;


</script>
```

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Button ID="btnDone" runat="server" Text="Done" onclick="btnDone_Click" />
            <asp:Literal ID="litnew" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateint() {
        alert(v);
    }
</script>

    <input type="button" onclick="updateint()" />
```

code behind

```
protected void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string kiss = LipImageCreator.createImage(); //this returns a file path

    litnewlipsurl.Text = "<script> v = '" + kiss + "'; </script>");

}
```

if i click the button run the updateint() function before i hit the btnDone button i get the alert saying '1' as expected. after i click the btnDone button the javascript is written to the literal as expected but when i click the updateint() button again i still get '1' and not the filepath i was expecting....

Answer (score 0):

You must use [ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) to get the ajax handler to run your script when the postback completes.

Comment: ive been trying this from your suggestion but im unsure if im using the right parameters as i dont know what they mean:
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "openDialogScript", "getAlertMsg();", true);

and on the front end i added         
function getAlertMsg() {
            alert("hi");
        }

outside the updatepanel, so i should get an alert when i click the button in the update panel

Comment: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(MyType), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), myscripttext, true);` - but you should read the docs on this function and try to understand the purpose of them.

Comment: still not getting anywhere with this. now in fiddler the only html that gets returned when i hit the button is what gets shown in the update panel, wouldnt Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript write the javascript at the top of the page which the update panel wont return? also i have tried RegisterClientScriptBlock which aparently is better than startup as registerstartupscript will only read the dom elements on page load